# Upgrading NodeJs in windows with NPM, without admin rights

Tags: node.js, npm

I've seen a lot of posts about upgrading Node.js but I haven't been able to get it to work yet. Is it possible to upgrade node in windows at a command prompt with npm, without admin rights? If so, please provide commands.

Thanks

Comment: You can't upgrade installed nodejs version without admin rights. But you can download separate binaries and run node from there.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info.

Comment: @Shaharyar that's exactly what I did, but then it's not clear how to override the PATH variables. Could you kindly clarify? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484293/change-default-path-of-nodejs-executable-in-windows-with-no-admin-rights