# Change default path of nodeJS executable in Windows (with no admin rights)

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I have no admin rights in my Windows PC, and the admin has already made a Node installation at `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, but this is version 12:

```
PS C:\Users\JO52900> node -v
v12.18.3
PS C:\Users\JO52900> Get-Command node

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     node.exe                                           12.18.3.0  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

I want now to **update** Node **without admin rights**, so I manually installed version 14 in `C:\Users\JO52900\nodeJS\node-v14.18.0-win-x64`

```
C:\Users\JO52900\nodeJS\node-v14.18.0-win-x64> .\node.exe -v
v14.18.0
```

Now I tried adding this folder to path:

```
$env:Path += "; C:\Users\JO52900\nodeJS\node-v14.18.0-win-x64"
```

but it does't work, `Get-Command node` always returns `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`.

TLDR: how can I **override the default Node path, without admin rights**, such that NPM and Powershell 'node' command use only the the new NodeJS folder which I have full access to (`C:\Users\JO52900\nodeJS\node-v14.18.0-win-x64`)?

Comment: `Set-Alias node C:\Users\JO52900\nodeJS\node-v14.18.0-win-x64\node.exe`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that's a simple solution, but it may not be comprehensive enough, because any non-PowerShell code that launches executable `node` would still invoke `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`, and I suspect that includes `npm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the system looks for executables specified by name only in the directories listed in the `$env:PATH` environment variable, the *order* in which they are listed matters: The *first* directory in which the executable is found is used.

Therefore, you must *prepend* rather than *append* your custom path:

```
$env:Path = "C:\Users\JO52900\nodeJS\node-v14.18.0-win-x64;$env:PATH"
```

- To make this change for all future PowerShell sessions, add the above command to your `$PROFILE` file (but note that PowerShell instances launched with `-NoProfile` will *not* see this modification).
- Unfortunately, modifying the registry-based *user-level* `Path` environment-variable definition for *all* processes (interactively via `sysdm.cpl` / programmatically via `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $newVal, 'User')`<sup>[1]</sup>) is *not* an option in this case, because the effective `$env:Path` value that processes see is a *composite* value, in which the *machine-level* value comes *first*.

---

<sup>[1] Actually, updating `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-based environment values such as `Path` with this method can have unexpected side effects; the proper solution, unfortunately, requires direct registry access - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375) for details.</sup>